# Minimize garbage collection

Tags: elasticsearch

How does garbage collection work in elastic search? Is any way to add the setting in the elastic search reading garbage collection, How to Minimize garbage collection memory in the elastic cluster?

Comment: Garbage collection is java’s in built memory management process. There are plenty of articles online detailing GC process. May I know if you are experiencing any issues concerning GC ? OutOfMemory errors ? GC pauses ? See https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble

Comment: My elastic search having a lot of memory Garbage Collection need to know the reasons for this large GC memory.

Comment: You can monitor garbage collection using for example [jvisualvm](https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/understanding-garbage-collection-using-visualvm-7e1520cb4ec0) . Changing young generation ratio might help but first you should observe how memory looks like when ES is running.

Comment: If ES is consuming high heap memory and you are seeing a lot of full Garbage Collections, you can start with looking at your heap settings. Is it too low ? If you believe heap memory setting is not an issue then capture a heap dump and look at which objects are occupying heap. Is your ES cluster adequately resourced in terms of memory, CPU etc ? Also, look at your shard configuration etc as each shard in itself cosumes resources and shard configuration should be proportional to the heap memory available on the node.